# Spring - Using an exception handler from an external jar for 2 other projects

Tags: java, spring, exceptionhandler, controller-advice

I have 2 projects that have the same exceptions and use the same exception handler.
So all of the exceptions and the exception handler were moved to an external module.

The exceptions are imported just fine, but the exception handler does not seem to be invoked.
As far as I understand, the handler should be invoked from the external jar if I have the @ComponentScan annotation.

Here's how my exception handler looks like:

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.*first-project*.controller",
        "com.*second-project*.controller"})
@ControllerAdvice(basePackages = {"com.*first-project*.controller",
        "com.*second-project*.controller"})
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

...

}
```

The exception handler worked fine when it was part of each project individually. Then it only had that project's path in the @ControllerAdvice annotation and had no @ComponentScan.

The external jar with the exception handler is currently imported with:

```
compile files('libs/*jar-name*.jar')
```

Comment: You should properly scan the components, both from the main project and from the extended jar. This scanning should be done on the main project(project-1 & project-2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding @Import(GlobalExceptionHandler.class) in the projects fixed the issue and the handler is being invoked properly now.

Answer (score 1):

> I was also facing the same issue what I did is:

> Step 1: In GlobalExceptionHandler.java declare controller as base      > packages using @ComponenetScan and @ControllerAdvice. Like as below

> @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.xxx.controller")
> @ControllerAdvice(basePackages = "com.xxx.controller")
> class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler{}

> Step 2: use @Import annotation and import GlobalExceptionHandler class > >in SpringbootMain Application class. Like as below
> @SpringBootApplication
> @Import(CustomExceptionHandler.class)
> public class SpringBootDemoApplication { }

Step 3: Include GlobalExceptionHandler maven dependency in other service projects wherever you want to use it.

---

Answer (score 0):

You should properly scan the components, both from the main project and from the extended jar. This scanning should be done on the main project(project-1 & project-2).

So, in `project-1 & project-2`, you have to scan the packages found in *jar-name*. You can create a separate configuration file or in your `GlobalExceptionHandler`.

```
@ControllerAdvice(basePackages = {"jar.package"})
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {...}
```

Comment: Spring Boot makes this much more convenient to set up with auto-configuration.

Comment: What do you mean by that? May be if there is an entry point for the library project, it just needs to just import that. do you intend this?

Comment: I tried adding @ComponentScan, leading to the external module's path, above the main method in the 2 projects, but it doesn't help.

Comment: In your question the scan seems to be in the shared lib, since you are scanning packages of `first-project` and `second-project`. But, for instance, if you import the dependency(shared) lib in `first-proj` and scan its components it should be ok. Or create an entry point in the lib and `@Import` the class. For a project, we are using this way.